# performance testing on google maps

Tags: performance, jmeter

Our client has implemented google maps on which user can select particular location from the map which can be added by the user and perform the next action of it. How should i test the dynamic value appearing from the google maps for a particular search criteria ..

for example here is the scenario

you search a location--> get the desired result go to google map--> click on the add button of that location and proceed futhur.

How should i design my testplan/scripts for the same.

I cannot go for correlation also because the value of data is not define in the previous sample using regular expression.I want to change the data dynamically in the same sampler.

Thanks :) :) :)

Comment: Better place to ask this is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/)

Comment: @Dmitri Tikhanski: can you please have a look into this